# Efficient assignment of percentile/rank in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rank

I have a couple of very large tables (over 400,000 rows) that look like the following:

```
+---------+--------+---------------+
| ID      | M1     | M1_Percentile |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 3684514 | 3.2997 | NULL          |
| 3684515 | 3.0476 | NULL          |
| 3684516 | 2.6499 | NULL          |
| 3684517 | 0.3585 | NULL          |
| 3684518 | 1.6919 | NULL          |
| 3684519 | 2.8515 | NULL          |
| 3684520 | 4.0728 | NULL          |
| 3684521 | 4.0224 | NULL          |
| 3684522 | 5.8207 | NULL          |
| 3684523 | 6.8291 | NULL          |
+---------+--------+---------------+...about 400,000 more
```

I need to assign each row in the `M1_Percentile` column a value that represents "the percent of rows with M1 values equal or lower to the current row's `M1` value"

In other words, I need:

[image]

I implemented this sucessfully, but it is FAR FAR too slow. If anyone could create a more efficient version of the following code, I would really appreciate it!

```sql
UPDATE myTable AS X JOIN (
SELECT
  s1.ID, COUNT(s2.ID)/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable) * 100 AS percentile
FROM
  myTable s1 JOIN myTable s2 on (s2.M1 <= s1.M1)
GROUP BY s1.ID
ORDER BY s1.ID) AS Z 
ON (X.ID = Z.ID) 
SET X.M1_Percentile = Z.percentile;
```

This is the (correct but slow) result from the above query if the number of rows is limited to the ones you see (10 rows):

```
+---------+--------+---------------+
| ID      | M1     | M1_Percentile |
+---------+--------+---------------+
| 3684514 | 3.2997 |            60 |
| 3684515 | 3.0476 |            50 |
| 3684516 | 2.6499 |            30 |
| 3684517 | 0.3585 |            10 |
| 3684518 | 1.6919 |            20 |
| 3684519 | 2.8515 |            40 |
| 3684520 | 4.0728 |            80 |
| 3684521 | 4.0224 |            70 |
| 3684522 | 5.8207 |            90 |
| 3684523 | 6.8291 |           100 |
+---------+--------+---------------+
```

Producing the same results for the entire 400,000 rows takes magnitudes longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot test this, but you could try something like:

```
update table t
set mi_percentile = (
    select count(*)
    from table t1
    where M1 < t.M1 / (
        select count(*)
        from table));
```

UPDATE:

```
update test t
set m1_pc = (
    (select count(*) from test t1 where t1.M1 < t.M1) * 100 /
    ( select count(*) from test));
```

This works in Oracle (the only database I have available).  I do remember getting that error in MySQL.  It is very annoying.

Comment: I get "You can't specify target table 'myTable' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: I had to change it a bit because MySQL was still giving me that same error.                                                                            update tmp1 AS t
inner join tmp1 AS q ON(q.ptime = t.ptime)
set t.slope_Percentile = (
    (select count(*) from (SELECT * FROM tmp1) t1 where t1.slope < t.slope) * 100 /
    ( select count(*) from (SELECT * FROM tmp1) tz));

Comment: This is the best version so far - it is 21.6% faster than Derek's version :)

Answer (score 1):

Fair warning: mysql isn't my native environment. However, after a little research, I think the following query should be workable:

```
UPDATE myTable AS X 
JOIN ( 
  SELECT  X.ID, (
      SELECT  COUNT(*)
      FROM    myTable X1
      WHERE   (X.M1, X.id) >= (X1.M1, X1.id) as Rank)
  FROM myTable as X
) AS RowRank
ON (X.ID = RowRank.ID)
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) as TotalCount 
  FROM myTable 
) AS TotalCount
SET X.M1_Percentile = RowRank.Rank / TotalCount.TotalCount;
```

Comment: I get "Unknown column 'X.M1' in 'where clause'"

Comment: Excellent, that cuts it down from 5.3s to 3.1s for 10,000 records

Comment: The other option is to insert all of your records into a temporary table that includes an auto-increment integer field (lets say, autoid) and cluster/order by M1 on the insert. Then, you would be able to simply do select autoid / count(*) from temptable. It's an extra step, but if you're able to do this in more than 1 query, then that might be your best bet.