# Convert UPDATE statement to a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

The following statement updates a column in a table named 'test'.

```
UPDATE test AS t
INNER JOIN test AS q ON(
    q.ptime = t.ptime
)
SET t.slope_Percentile =(
    (
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    test
            )AS t1
        WHERE
            t1.slope < t.slope
    )* 100 /(
        SELECT
            count(*)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    test
            ) AS tz
    )
);
```

Instead of updating the column I would like to receive a SELECT statement that gives a readout of each row (that would be updated if it was an UPDATE statement).

More information (if needed) about the nature of the tables and the goal of the code is here:
[Efficient assignment of percentile/rank in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086751/efficient-assignment-of-percentile-rank-in-mysql)

Comment: You should fix the query first... You are joining in the table as `q`, but you never use that in the query. You are doing `select count(*) from (select * from test)` when just `select count(*) from test` would do.

Comment: This in fact does not work in MYSQL. It says" "You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.ptime,
( 
    ( 
        SELECT 
            count(*) 
        FROM 
            ( 
                SELECT 
                    * 
                FROM 
                    test 
            )AS t1 
        WHERE 
            t1.slope < t.slope 
    )* 100 /( 
        SELECT 
            count(*) 
        FROM 
            ( 
                SELECT 
                    * 
                FROM 
                    test 
            ) AS tz 
    ) 
)  AS slope_Percentile
 FROM test AS t 
--INNER JOIN test AS q ON
--q.ptime = t.ptime
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT *, (
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM test AS t1
    WHERE t1.slope < t.slope) * 100 /
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM test as tz)) as newvalue
FROM test AS t;
```

Comment: Nope - gives me an error; [SQL] SELECT *, (
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM test AS t1
    WHERE t1.slope < t.slope) * 100 /
    (SELECT count(*)
    FROM test) 
FROM test);
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM test)' at line 7

Comment: Forgot MYSQL needs alises for the tables

Comment: a parenthesis is missing, just before the FROM, add it and will work.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.  Fixed.